# how to add underscore to front end javascript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I added the `underscore` using `npm install underscore` but I am stuck on how to use it on front end .On backend `var _ = require('underscore')` may work and something like `import {x} from underscore.js` may work on front end which is ofcourse not able to work on my case.

I would like to know what is the best way of adding packages on front end (ex: I want to use bootstrap on all html files but not through using `<script src="bootstrap.js">` which makes hazard as add multiple script files "

Answer (score 0):

Just add script tag and src of underscore from npm modules so you should be able to use in your app.

```
<script src="node_modules/underscore"></script>
```

if you don't want to use script tag then you need a JS package manager like JSPM or `SystemJS` or `webpack` to load in your app

If you are using any **framework** like angular then you don't need to add `underscore` to each file enough if you are add get it `Index file.`

There are some options it's all about what kind of app you are building witch `tool` you are using.